# Is P(B) and B the same in probability

Tags: probability

An electrical connection consists of $6$ components, which work independently of each other.

Let $A_i$ be the event that component nr. $i$ works ($i = 1,\ldots, 6$), and assume that these have probabilities
$$P(A_1) = 0.6, P (A_2) = 0.8, P (A_3) = 0.5$$
$$P (A_4) = 0.6, P (A_5) = 0.8  P (A_6) = 0.7$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCzMP.png

The task) *We define $B = A1 ∪ A4$. What is P ($B$)? What is the interpretation of B? *

I thought that $B$ would be the same as P($B$)? and $B$ is to check the probability if the circuit works. at least for $A_1$ and $A_4$. But my friend was I was wrong.

Comment: $B$ is an event. $P(B)$ is the probability that it happens. They are different.

Comment: If I wanted to know the probability that there is electricity it would be                P(B)=(A1-A4)-(A1∩A4)=0,84

Comment: Yes, but the syntex is wrong: $P(B)=P(A_1)+P(A_4)-P(A_1\cap A_4)$